# Oracle display only rows that belong to the logged in user

Tags: oracle11g

I have CUSTOMER table created by user DAVID in oracle, also I have populate the table with data using same user.
How am I going to create a VIEW named as MY_VIEW to display only rows that belong to the logged in user?

Comment: have a column in the table or another table which stores the user inserting the record. Then in your view , filter records by user in where clause.

Comment: is there any way to know who created the row such as we can know who created the table ?

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause, add the row in the table that contains user_name and compare it the current user. As below:

Where user_name in (SELECT USERNAME FROM V$SESSION);